# Objects are not valid as a React child ( found object: object with keys ($$typeof,type,key,ref,props,_owner,_store})

Tags: firebase, ecmascript-6, react-native

I am trying to use firebase on my react native app. But it gives an error.
[image: Image is here]

my App.js code is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem today. I ran a diff on the source code between 5.0.3 and 5.0.4 and found that the exports have changed. I also found that if I change the import statement to the following that it works with the latest version (5.3.0):

`import firebase from '@firebase/app'`

If you're using eslint you'll probably get a complaint that it should be listed in the project dependencies, but you can ignore that.

You'll probably also want to use the actual features of firebase rather than just the core import. For example, to use the authentication module you'd add the following:

`import '@firebase/auth'`

Comment: you saved my life! now my react-native project works flawlessly with firebase 5.0.3. thank you!

Comment: I spent almost 10 hours figuring this out after upgrading all my packages. I thought it was something to do with redux upgrade. And removed all of redux and used local state! And it has got something to do with Firebase! Silly error, really. Wish I used the right keywords in Google to begin my trouble-shooting. Using $$typeof got me here.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an issue with firebase@5.0.4. On your command line run npm install firebase@5.0.3. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm not sure what happened with this version firebase@5.0.4. I also faced this issue too. But there is a workaround to resolve this issue.

1st step: Remove your import statement: import firebase from 'firebase';

2nd step:

 1. Create a local function like this:

    initializeFirebase() {
    const firebase = require("firebase");

    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: 'apikey',
        authDomain: 'domain.com',
        databaseURL: 'databaseUrl',
        projectId: 'projectId',
        storageBucket: 'storageurl',
        messagingSenderId: 'senderId'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

 2. Call it in your componentDidMount()

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initializeFirebase();
  }

Hope, it helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with firebase version 5.0.6 whereas downgrading to a version will resolve this issue.for example try this

$ npm install --save firebase@5.0.4

If version 5.0.4 is also not working for you than try version 4.9.1 as this is what i am using and it resolved this issue for me

$npm install --save firebase@4.9.1